# Return "creation date" value from database - laravel/vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

In my laravel file I need to show the creation date of the task the user is viewing.

In the database I have the "tasks" table where the "created_at" column is present. it stores a date in the format: 2021-11-11 14:21:22
I would like to display the date (at this moment I am not receiving anything) in the format 11 Nov 2021. Can anyone help me out?

This is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web\Back\App\Projects;

use App\Events\Task\TaskDeadlineChanged;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Column;
use App\Models\Task;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProjectTasksController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('tenant.user');
        $this->middleware('plan.limit')->only('store', 'update');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created task.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'content' => ['required', 'max:255'],
        ]);


        $column = Column::where('uuid', $request->column)->firstOrFail();

        $this->authorize('create', [Task::class, $column->project]);

        $column->tasks()->create([
            'content' => $request->input('content'),
            'index' => $column->tasks->count(),
        ]);

        return back();
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified task.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'content' => ['required', 'max:255'],
        ]);
        $task = Task::where('uuid', $request->task)->firstOrFail();
        $this->authorize('update', $task);

        $task->update([
            'content' => $request->input('content'),
            'due_date' => $request->input('due_date'),
            'created_at' => $request->input('created_at'),
            'priority' => $request->input('priority'),
            'description' => $request->input('description'),
        ]);

        if ($task->wasChanged('due_date')) {
            event(new TaskDeadlineChanged($task));
        }

        $this->updateAssignedTaskUser($task, $request);

        $this->updateTaskStatus($task, $request);

        return back();
    }

    /**
     * Delete the specified task.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $task = Task::where('uuid', $request->task)->firstOrFail();

        $this->authorize('delete', $task);

        $task->delete();

        return back();
    }

    /**
     * Set or unset assigned task user.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Task $task
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function updateAssignedTaskUser($task, $request)
    {
        if ($request->input('user_uuid')) {
            return $task->assignTo(
                User::where('uuid', $request->input('user_uuid'))->firstOrFail()
            );
        }

        return $task->unassignUser();
    }

    /**
     * Mark task as completed or incomplete.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Task $task
     * @param \App\Http\Request $request
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function updateTaskStatus($task, $request)
    {
        if ($request->input('is_completed')) {
            return $task->markAsCompleted();
        }

        return $task->markAsIncompleted();
    }
}
```

and this is my modal-task.vue

```
<div class="inline-block">{{ task.created_at }}</div>
```

---

```
props: {
    users: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },
    projectUuid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    taskUuid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    isCompleted: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    userUuid: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    priority: {
        type: Number,
        default: null
    },
    dueDate: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
```

---

```
data() {
    return {
        task: new Form({
            uuid: this.uuid,
            content: this.content,
            is_completed: this.isCompleted,
            user_uuid: this.userUuid,
            due_date: this.dueDate,
            priority: this.priority,
            created_at: this.createdAt,
            description: this.description
        })
    }
},
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#timestamps, https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-introduction and https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php should give you all you need. You have a `Task` model, `created_at` is by default a `Carbon` instance, and the `->format()` method uses php's `DateTime::format` options to convert the date to your format. See if you can put that all together.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for the reply. The first problem though is that I still can't see the date, not even in the database format. It is the only field that I cannot recall but I don't understand what is wrong with the code. After I will try to format it as directed by you. Do you have any idea why I don't see the date?

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69930135/edit) and include your `Task.php` Model? I'm not sure what you mean by "can't see the date" Also, if you run `php artisan tinker`, then `Task::first()->created_at`, what do you see? I don't know `vue.js`, so I can't really speak to if that is the issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by [setting the casts property on the tasks model](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting).  So for the format you require it would be set like this:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:d M Y',
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first problem though is that I still can't see the date, not even in the database format. It is the only field that I cannot recall but I don't understand what is wrong with the code.
After I will try to format it as directed by you. Do you have any idea why I don't see the date?

Comment: A number of things could be happening here. Do you have any fields set in the $hidden / $visible property on the Task model? Are you mutating data in the controller where you load the tasks?

Comment: no, no fields set to hidden. The controller instead is entirely published in the post ...